# How to retrieve the value from textbox using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ngmodel

```
$scope.add=function()
                {
                    //How to retrieve the value of textbox
                }

<input type='text'><button ng-click='add()'></button>
```

When I click on the button, how can I retrieve the textbox value in the controller and add that value to the table dynamically?

Answer (score 13):

Assign `ng-model` to it so that variable will be available inside `scope` of controller.

**Markup**

```
<input type='text' ng-model="myVar"/>
<button type="button" ng-click='add(myVar)'></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind the text field using [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Example:

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.newItem = {
  title: ''
}

$scope.add = function(item) {
  $scope.items.push(item);
  $scope.newItem = { title: '' }; // set newItem to a new object to lose the reference
}
```

---

```
<input type='text' ng-model='newItem.title'><button ng-click='add(newItem)'>Add</button>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{ item.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

To take your data from `textbox`, you should use `ng-model` attribute on the HTML element. On the `button` element you can use `ng-click` with a parameter which is your `ng-model`

Example:
Your HTML:

```
<input type='text' ng-model="YourTextData"/>
<button type="button" ng-click='add(YourTextData)'></button>
```

Your Js:

```
$scope.add=function(YourTextData){

       //Put a debugger in here then check the argument

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-model in your textbox to bind them to your scope variables

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value1">
<input type="text" ng-model="value2">
```

Then declare the variables inside your controller and use them in your function

```
$scope.value1 = 0;
$scope.value2 = 0;
$scope.add=function()
    {
       // Example
       console.log($scope.value1 + $scope.value2);
    }
```